# Set Z value to a linestring from a postgis raster

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

I have a table with multilinestring geometries that can be updated or inserted by external users, and a raster table with elevation values.

I want to write a trigger that sets the z value of each point in the line from the DEM.

Probably I can write a function that iterates over the linestring points with `ST_NPoint` or `ST_DumpPoints`. Gets the elevation from the raster with `ST_Value`. And recreates the point with `ST_SetPoint`.

But, is there any easier way to to this?

Comment: It's hard to see how you would avoid iterating over the linestring points, given that different points on the linestring may have different z values.

Comment: I don't see it either. But iterating over the points with a LOOP is terrible slow. Maybe PostGIS has a function that I didn't know about that already to this.

Comment: You don't need a loop for the method you suggest in your question. 1. Dump the points with `ST_DumpPoints` (making sure to retain the path id of each linestring, the id of the multilinestring, and the order of the points). 2. Calculate the z values with `ST_Value`.  3. Add the z value to each point with `ST_MakePoint'. 4. Use `ST_Makeline` to aggregate the rows back to multilinestrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer for producing a `LineStringZ`:

```
WITH points2d AS (
  SELECT NEW.gid,
         ST_DumpPoints(NEW.geog::geometry) AS point2d
  FROM lines
)
SELECT
  gid,
  ST_MakeLine(
    ST_Translate(
      ST_Force3DZ((point2d).geom), 
      0, 
      0, 
      ST_Value(
        rast, 
        (point2d).geom
      )
    ) 
  ORDER BY (point2d).path) AS linestringz
FROM points2d 
  LEFT JOIN elevations ON ST_Intersects(rast, (point2d).geom)
GROUP BY gid;
```